# vscode extension API - how to get only visible lines of editor

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've searched the documentation but I could find nothing.

is there a way to get only the "visible" text of the document in the editor (so, I don't want to get the text / lines of hidden text by scrollbar)?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's now possible via `TextEditor.visibleRanges`

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14756

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible with the current API.

You can make a feature request by creating an issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues

Comment: thanks, opened issue here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14756